# SSRS Reports in ASP.NET 5

Tags: reporting-services, asp.net-core, reportviewer

Is there any way to display SSRS reports in ASP.NET 5? I tried iframe but ASP.NET 5 does not allow iframe to display external webpage.

Comment: what does iframe, an html tag, have to do with asp.net 5?

Answer (score 0):

I found this project on github that should work for you.
https://github.com/armanio123/ReportViewerForMvc ?

Are you just trying to link to a report server from an iFrame?  If so, you need to set your x-frame-options on your source application.